# Removing strings from multiple files

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to organise and rename some roms I got, I've already used command line to remove regions like " (USA)" and " (Japan)" including the space in front from filenames. Now I need to update my .cue files, I've tried the following but something is missing...

```
grep --include={*.cue} -rnl './' -e " (USA)" | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/ (USA)//g' @

grep --include={*.cue} -rnl './' -e " (Europe)" | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/ (Europe)//g' @

grep --include={*.cue} -rnl './' -e " (Japan)" | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/ (Japan)//g' @
```

I got it to work on one occasion but can't see to get it right again...

Comment: what is wrong with `sed -i 's/ (Japan)//g;s/ (Europe)//g;s/ (USA)//g' *.cue`?

Comment: @7171u `sed -i 's/(\(Japan|Europe|USA\))//g' *.cue`

Comment: @123 Post your  improvement after adding a space that must be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome thanks, I used:

```
sed -i 's/ (Japan)//g;s/ (Europe)//g;s/ (USA)//g' *.cue
```